# Express JS Get / not working with local host

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to build some routes with Express.js and I can't seem to get a route to register on local host. When I go to localhost:4002 everything is fine and my static page registers. But when I go to localhost:4002/messages I keep getting the error Cannot GET /messages. I'm learning this from a video and I have the exact same code as the video so I'm kind of lost on what the issue can be. Code below.

```
const app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname));

var messages = [
    {name: 'Tim',message: "Hi"},
    {name: 'Joe',message: "Hey"}
];

app.get('/messages', (req, res) => {
    res.send('hello');
})

   const server = app.listen(4002, () => {
    console.log(`server is listening on port ${server.address().port}`);
});
```

Comment: I tried your code and it worked for me

Comment: I was honestly afraid someone was going to say that =(

Comment: Can you add the whole file. Also I recommend you to use routers don't make requests from app.js or index.js. It will be more organized.

Comment: https://github.com/Jmarch0909/Messenger

Good to know about the routers. I'm just getting started with express and this is a pretty early roadblock since I can't even test out my routes.

Comment: your port number might be taken from something else. Check your NodeJS console

Comment: The port number should be good because I can get localhost:4002 to come up, just not localhost:4002/messages. how would I check that in the node console anyhow though?

Answer (score 0):

Just checked your Github page and I think that problem is in that function:

```
function getMessages() {
$.get('localhost:4002/messages', (data) => {
    console.log(data);
})
```

Change this code to this:

```
function getMessages() {
    $.get('/messages', (data) => {
        console.log(data);
    })
```

Hope it works.

Comment: I tried that and still no luck. I can't even get the page to come up my browser just gives me a 404 error saying that there is no path for messages.

Answer (score 0):

Similar issue to what I had, your `app.use(express.static(__dirname));` might be pointing to the wrong directory space. Try:

```
const path = require('path');
let reqpath = path.join(__dirname, "../"); //using static
app.use(express.static(reqpath));
```

Note: The `../` is the letting it know to look in the directory above it.

My code hierarchy looks something like this:

```
- ./index.html
- ./app/server.js
```